# Magento 2 - Get Cart Total in Observer

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, payment-methods

I needed to get the cart total in my observer.

Here is the code I have:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DisablePayment implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_logger;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    LoggerInterface $logger
  ) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
  }

  /**
   * @param Observer $observer
   *
   * @return void
   */

   public function getCustomAttribute(){
      if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
        return $customerAtt = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getData('credit');
      endif;
   }

  public function execute( Observer $observer )
  {
    $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
    $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

    if($method_instance == 'payroll')
    {
      $customerAttribute = 300;
      $total = 400;

      if($customerAttribute < $total)
      {
        $result->setData('is_available', false);
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cartObj = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$subTotal = $cartObj->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); //Current Cart Subtotal
$grandTotal = $cartObj->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //Cart Grand total
```

Then I just used this - $total = $grandTotal.

Good luck!

Comment: Using $objectManager directly is not a good approach to follow. You should use dependency injection for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Since you should not use the object manager a better way would be to use the checkout session:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DisablePayment implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected $_logger;
  protected $checkoutSession;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    LoggerInterface $logger
  ) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_logger = $logger;
  }

  /**
   * @param Observer $observer
   *
   * @return void
   */

   public function getCustomAttribute(){
      if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
        return $customerAtt = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getData('credit');
      }
   }

  public function execute( Observer $observer )
  {
    $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
    $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $total = $quote->getGrandTotal();
    if($method_instance == 'payroll')
    {
      $customerAttribute = 300;

      if($customerAttribute < $total)
      {
        $result->setData('is_available', false);
      }
    }
  }
```